# Pythonic ways of traversing imported constants

Tags: python

I'm importing some constants from my file `constants.py` like this:

```
from constants import (SOME_CONST, OTHER_CONST, ANOTHER_ONE)
```

This constants are filenames and I'm reading data out of them, what I want to achieve is this:

```
for filename in [SOME_CONST, OTHER_CONST, ANOTHER_ONE]:
    # process file
```

**constants.py**

```
SOME_CONST = "filename.txt"
OTHER_CONST = "myfile.xml"
ANOTHER_ONE = "file.csv"
```

But I want to know if there is a way to avoid declaring the list in the for, like traverse or build a list of imported constants, because there can be many constants not just 3 like the example and it is error prone, since I would need to import the constant and add it to the list, I just want to import it and work with whatever is imported.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'imported constants'; they are all just globals. Are you importing *all* names from `constants`, or is there a specific pattern to them?

Comment: `import constants; dir(constants)` may help you. It will list everything that is inside that module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is no pattern, I updated my question.

Comment: @Davidmh that is useful, sadly, the file contains many other constants not used in this module.

Comment: You can specify a filter, so you only set it once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot list 'all imported constants', no. They are just more globals in your current module.

Your options are to:

1. list all names on the `constants` module:

   ```
   import constants

   for name in dir(constants):
       const = getattr(constants, name)
   ```

   You can filter those names if they  follow a pattern:

   ```
   for name in dir(constants):
       if name.startswith('FOO_'):
   ```

   The filter can be a simple as checking that the name is all uppercase.
2. declare the list as part of your constants module, and import *that* instead.
3. declare a list of names in your current module, and use that to 'import' your constants:

   ```
   import constants

   const_names = ['SOME_CONST', 'OTHER_CONST', 'ANOTHER_ONE']
   for const_name in const_names:
       const = getattr(constants, const_name)
   ```

Comment: Option 3 is probably the simplest way to select a subset of constants while honoring DRY.

Comment: Appending a prefix `PRE_` to the name of my constants and filtering them seems to be the proper option.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza If all your constants are upper case only, and nothing else in your module is upper case only, you can filter by `if name.upper() == name:`.  That way you don't need to add that prefix.

Answer (score 2):

If you respect the python convention of naming globals in upper case (and only them), you could do, as suggested by Davidmh:

```
for filename in [i for i in dir(constants) where i.upper() == i]:
    ...
```